# How to know when the Silverlight VisualStateManager.GoToState transition has completed?

Tags: silverlight, visualstatemanager

I am using the Silverlight `VisualStateManager.GoToState` method to transition my control from one state to another. This all works fine and the transition animations works great. But I want to know when the transition has completed so I can then start other actions in my code. Is there an event or other mechanism I can use to discover when the transition to another state has completed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The control immediately goes to the state given. The animations that this triggers can be thought of as a side-effect. You can determine when a triggered timeline is complete via its Completed event:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.completed%28VS.95%29.aspx

Colin E.